# Ошибка при textView.setText в RecylerViewAdapter

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, adapter

Привет. У меня такая проблема: у меня есть `RecyclerView` и к нему, соответственно адаптер. Списочек я заполняю элементами (`CardView`), ставлю на них обработчик событий, всё ок, всё пашет.

НО: на моём экране помимо `RecyclerView` имеется `TextView`. И вот обработчику событий списка я говорю: а поставь-ка ты мне в тот `TextView` такое вот значение. Это значение берётся из `CardView` на который мы нажали. И вот, запуская приложение на эмуляторе, я нажимаю на `CardView` ииии... Приложение вылетает с такой вот ошибкой:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

Я в растерянности... Прошу вашей помощи. Вот код адаптера:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<String> records;

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView tName;
        private CardView cardView;
        private ImageView tIcon;
        private TextView tCost;
        private Button add;
        int green1, green2, green3, green4, green5, green6, white;
        TextView productsText; //Мой треклятый TextView

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            green1 = itemView.getResources().getColor(R.color.green1);
            green2 = itemView.getResources().getColor(R.color.green2);
            green3 = itemView.getResources().getColor(R.color.green3);
            green4 = itemView.getResources().getColor(R.color.green4);
            green5 = itemView.getResources().getColor(R.color.green5);
            green6 = itemView.getResources().getColor(R.color.green6);
            white = itemView.getResources().getColor(R.color.white);

            productsText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            costText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);

            tName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
            tCost = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
            tIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
            add = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        }
    }

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<String> records) {
        this.records = records;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }


    int COST = 0;
    String zakaz = "";

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

        /* ТУТ Я ЗАПОЛНЯЮ СПИСОК ЭЛЕМЕНТАМИ */


        viewHolder.add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Тут я беру моё String значение из элемента и сую его в переменную zakaz
                if (zakaz.length() == 0) {
                    zakaz = zakaz + viewHolder.tName.getText().toString();
                } else {
                    zakaz = zakaz + ", " + viewHolder.tName.getText().toString();

                }

                //Ну и ещё одно значение (оно int, но я его быренько в String)
                String sto = viewHolder.tCost.getText().toString();
                int coster = Integer.parseInt(sto.replace(" руб.","");

                COST = COST + coster;

                //Тут я, собственно, устанавливаю значения в TextView (метод чуть ниже)
                setTexts(zakaz, COST, viewHolder);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return records.size();
    }

    //Вот этот метод:
    public void setTexts(String zakaz, int Cost, ViewHolder view){
        view.costText.setText(Cost);
        view.productsText.setText(zakaz);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по:

> на моём экране помимо `RecyclerView` имеется `TextView`.

`TextView` находится в некотором главном `layout` – `layout` активити, в которой находится `RecyclerView`. Однако ищите этот `TextView` Вы совсем в другом файле разметки (в `R.layout.item`):

```
productsText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

А так как в `R.layout.item` элемента с таким `id` нет, то он инициализируется `null`'ем.

Можете в адаптере объявить интерфейс:

```
public interface OnRecyclerViewClickListener {
    void onItemClick(String text);
}
```

Далее в адаптере добавляете поле и сеттер для листнера:

```
private OnRecyclerViewClickListener mOnRecyclerViewClickListener;
...
public void setOnRecyclerViewClickListener(OnRecyclerViewClickListener onRecyclerViewClickListener) {
    mOnRecyclerViewClickListener = onRecyclerViewClickListener;
}
```

Далее в методе `setTexts(...)` адаптера заменяете:

```
view.productsText.setText(zakaz);
```

на

```
if (mOnRecyclerViewClickListener != null){
    mOnRecyclerViewClickListener.onItemClick(zakaz);
}
```

и в активити регистрируете листнер:

```
mAdapter.setOnRecyclerViewClickListener(new RecyclerViewAdapter.OnRecyclerViewClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(String text) {
        mTextView.setText(text);
    }
});
```

Разумеется, в этой активити должно быть поле:

```
private TextView mTextView;
```

и в методе `onCreate(...)` активити Вы должны его инициализировать:

```
mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

Comment: Господи, огромное вам спасибо!)